# hreflang and canonical tag for new country specific website - different base domain

Tags: canonical-url, hreflang

I have a little different situation compared to most other questions which asks for hreflang and canonical tags for country specific version of websites.

This is an SEO related question and I was hoping to get some insight on your recommendations.

- We have an existing Australian website - say - ausnight.com.au
- now we want to launch a UK version of this website - the domain is - uknight.co.uk
- please note, we are not only changing from .com.au to .co.uk.... but the base domain name as well changed - from **ausnight** to **uknight**
- as you can understand, the audience for both websites is different.

Both websites has most pages same with same contents.... the questions I have is -

1) Should we put canonical tag on the new website pages?

2) If we don't put canon tag on new website pages, what is the impact on the SEO ranking of current website?

3) I believe we need to put hreflang tag on both websites to tell google that we have another language version (en-au vs en-gb) of the same page. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct, you do need to implement hreflang in your scenario.

Being a type of canonical command, hreflang can and should be used when working with URLs from different domains; [Google themselves say so here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en):

> *Alternate URLs do not need to be in the same domain.*

So yes, the regular implementation rules for hreflang should be used here (described in the mentioned document above).

Comment: what's your position on using canonical tag? Query 1 above.

Comment: HREFLANG is a canonical tag